# Encryption Scheme & Perfect Secrecy [Katz & Lindell]

Tags: encryption, security-definition

An *encryption scheme* consists of the following data

- a plaintext space $\mathcal M$
- a ciphertext space $\mathcal C$
- a key space $\mathcal K$
- a key generating algorithm Gen
- encryption and decryption algorithms $\operatorname{Enc}_k$ and $\operatorname{Dec}_k$ for each key $k\in \mathcal K$

I would like some clarification on the following extract from Katz & Lindell:

[image: picture]

More specifically, my question is:
What does, say, $P(K=k)$ mean exactly? What is the domain and codomain of the random variable $K$? What is the set $\{K=k\}$? Also, what is the domain of Gen?

Comment: This was [cross posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420323/encryption-scheme-perfect-secrecy-katz-lindell) on Math. Please don't cross post on multiple sites. It is against SE rules.

Comment: [This](http://fkraiem.org/probability.pdf) could be useful...

Answer (score 1):

> What does, say, $P(K=k)$ mean exactly?

It signifies the probability that the key $K$ selected by the key generation algorithm $Gen$ is the value $k$.

The notation he is using is that $P(condition)$ (actually, they use $Pr[condition]$, perhaps to emphasize that $P$ isn't a function on the value condition, but rather its probability distribution) is the probability that the condition is true.  For example, if I flip a fair coin, we have $P(\text{heads}) = 0.5$

> What is the domain and codomain of the random variable $K$?

The key space $\mathcal K$

> What is the set $\{K=k\}$?

It's not a set; it's an equality which is true with a certain probability.

> Also, what is the domain of Gen?

The key space $\mathcal K$

Comment: The domain of Gen is the key space?

Comment: $P$ or $Pr$ is a probability measure and as such it takes as input a set. Usually when one writes, say, $P(X=0)$, this is shorthand for $P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = 0\}$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space and $X:\Omega\to \Bbb R$ some random variable.

Comment: So in short, I still don't know what $P(K = k)$ means. What is the sample space on which $K$ is defined and what is its codomain? What is the set of events on which $Pr$ is defined? @poncho

Comment: BTW: what do you mean by 'codomain'?  $K$ isn't a function, it's a random variable...

Comment: Random variables are in particular functions......... @poncho

Comment: The input of `Gen` is a constant $n$-bit string, which is overwritten by a non-deterministic Turing machine to give a $n$-bit key. The *codomain* is $\mathcal{K}$, though.